# Print via Google Cloud Print without opening dialog window

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-print

Is there anyway I could print using Google Cloud Print without opening the dialog window?

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/cloudprint/client/cpgadget.js">
</script>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var gadget = new cloudprint.Gadget();
    gadget.setPrintButton(document.getElementById("custom_print_button"));
    gadget.setPrintDocument("text/html", "Print", document.documentElement.innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

And I would like to call it on window load, which is not working as well.

Comment: Your code is only a gadget, you need to use its API, I saw that was 1 month ago, maybe you made it with the API, can you help me with your code or documentation?, I'm trying it(to use API of google cloud print), but I don't understand how to make it works.Thanks

Comment: I used this implementation: https://github.com/yasirsiddiqui/php-google-cloud-print